# How to plot multiple markers on Google Maps from Firebase databse?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to grab coordinates from Firebase database, and plot markers on Google Maps.

This is my current code on Google Maps:

```
 mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Markers");
 mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            String alatLng= (String) dataSnapshot.child("coordinates").getValue();


            String[] blatLng = alatLng.split(",");

            double blatitude = Double.parseDouble(blatLng[0]);
            double blongitude = Double.parseDouble(blatLng[1]);

            LatLng clatLng = new LatLng(
                    blatitude,
                    blongitude
            );




            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(clatLng)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker7)));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

My database looks like this:

```
Markers
 -UID
     coordinates: ("55,55")
 -UID2
     coordinates:("66,66")
```

My coordinates value is under each users' uid. 
I believe it's not working becuase the coordinates value is under another child, but I'm not sure. Could use help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  Lat = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue().toString();
longi = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue().toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Lat + longi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
m2=  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Lat),Double.parseDouble(longi))).title("My Location"));
mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20);
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Lat), Double.parseDouble(longi));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
```

Comment: Do something like this,it is working like charm for me,i have a node in firebase named on device name and has two child Latitude and Longitude